# Opening android application from background

Tags: android

Whenever my android application goes into the background i always wants to open my password activity every time application comes from background, How can i implement this functionality in my code?

Comment: in onpause and onresume

Comment: make clear about you need

Comment: according to application requirement, whenever app goes into the background, it should not directly open the activity from where it gone in the background but first opens the launcher activity and then open the activity from where it previously gone in background.\

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Add New Class Global

   ```
   public class Global extends Application
   {

   private static Global mInstance;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       mInstance = this;

       ApplicationLifeCycleHandler handler = new ApplicationLifeCycleHandler();
       registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(handler);
       registerComponentCallbacks(handler);
   }


   public static Global getInstance(){
       return mInstance;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Add this line in your manifest in application tag like

   ```
     <application
           android:name=".Global"
     </application>
   ```
3. Add this class and open your password intent when app come background to foreground like

   ```
     public class ApplicationLifeCycleHandler implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, ComponentCallbacks2 {

   public static Activity activity;

   private static final String TAG = ApplicationLifeCycleHandler.class.getSimpleName();
   public static boolean isInBackground = true;

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
       this.activity = activity;
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
       this.activity = activity;

       if (isInBackground) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PasswordActivity.class);//set your password activity 
           activity.startActivity(intent);

           Log.d(TAG, "app went to foreground");
           isInBackground = false;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configuration) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onLowMemory() {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTrimMemory(int i) {
       if (i == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
           Log.d(TAG, "app went to background");
           isInBackground = true;

       }
   }
   }
   ```

Hope it will help you and please let me know if you are facing any issue. Thanks